# Remove Left Margin of Microsoft Chart Control

Tags: winforms, mschart

How to remove the left margin of a Microsoft Chart Control (Shown as a red rectangle)?

The chart control is docked in the parent form. It seems that this margin is dynamic and depends on the chart width.

I cannot find such an option. Do I need to work with ChartArea location?

[image]

This is a .NET C#, WinForms application.

Comment: ChartArea.Position.X.  You can't make it negative.  Undock it, move it to the left, anchor it on all sides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code worked for me:

```
    Chart1.ChartAreas[0].Position.X = 0;
```

Comment: Just setting this attribute breaks my chart in .NET 4.7.1, probably because it deactivates the auto sizing of the chart area for all position values (X, Y, Width, Height).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to remove all the paddings:

```
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].Position.X = 0;

Chart1.ChartAreas[0].Position.Width = 100;

Chart1.ChartAreas[0].Position.Height = 100;

Chart1.ChartAreas[0].Position.Y = 0;
```